# Is there an Amazon api

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway

Hi there I am wondering if there is an amazon api that lets you browse there catalogue, eg item name price, competitors and so on. I am  aware of two amazon api's one used for promoting there products but I am a little unsure of the other one and if I can use the other api for my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [Advertising API](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/), which seems to do what you want.

You can browse their nodes using [this](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/use-cases/organization-of-items-on-amazon/browse-nodes.html).